# Laravel - Upload to Existing Model Record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, controller, upload

Maybe it's because I'm tired, but I can't seem to get a simple upload working for one of my models.

On the show details page of my customers (who are NOT users) model, I have a simple form where a user can upload the logo of the customer.

The form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/customers/i/{{$customer->url_string}}" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="logoUpload">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The Controller:

```
public function logoUpload(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('logoUpload')){
        $path = Storage::putFile('public/customer/uploads', new File(request('logoUpload')));

        $customer->car_logo = $path;
        $customer->save();

        return back();
    }   
}
```

I know the issue is that I haven't defined $customer in the controller since the file does actually store itself in the correct folder after I click submit, but it does not hit the database at all.

### Update

The current customer details url:

```
http://localhost:8000/customers/i/dsdado9a98w78721
```

The web definition for the post route:

```
Route::post('/customers/i/{customer}', 'CustomerController@logoUpload');
```

Comment: can you show your route definition and the current url you are hitting?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question with both.

Comment: what field on `Customer` does that route parameter reference?

Comment: {customer} references a field called url_string in my customer table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a hidden field in your form that contains the customer id and then use it in your controller to update it with the new file path, here is an example:

**View**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/customers/i/{{$customer->url_string}}" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="logoUpload">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <!-- customer_id field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{$customer->id}}">
    <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function logoUpload(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('logoUpload')){
        $path = Storage::putFile('public/customer/uploads', new File(request('logoUpload')));

        // get customer
        $customer = Customer::find($request->customer_id);

        $customer->car_logo = $path;
        $customer->save();

        return back();
    }   
}
```

Comment: they are using a route parameter for the 'identifier' they want ... the URL itself identifies the customer

Comment: I don't think that `url_string` is an identifier, however using a customer id would be fast because it's already an indexed field

Comment: maybe they dont want to expose ids, they seem to have purposefully used the `url_string` as the route parameter in the URL, they could have used the `id` very easily ... people also use 'slugs' as identifiers and they aren't autoincrement ids  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some options, here is a simple one, with only adjusting that controller method:

```
public function logoUpload(Request $request, $customer)
{
    $customer = Customer::where('url_string', $customer)->firstOrFail();

    if($request->hasFile('logoUpload')){
        $path = Storage::putFile('public/customer/uploads', new File(request('logoUpload')));

        $customer->car_logo = $path;
        $customer->save();

        return back();
    }
    ...
}
```

We have added a parameter to the method signature to accept the route parameter. We then find the model via `url_string` matching that parameter.

You also could setup route model binding as well to do the resolving of that model based on the route parameter for you.